# Dev Tools -> Application -> Clear site data not working to clear cache

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache

I very often have css/javascript caching issues in Google Chrome and similar (I use Brave).

I noticed that:

> Dev Tools -> Application -> Clear site data: **doesn't work**

but

> Chrome -> Settings -> Clear cache for last 24 hours: works (and deleted also other site data which is undesiderable)

Any idea why?

Comment: Sounds like something that should be reported on https://crbug.com, but make sure to provide all the details needed to reproduce the issue.